# Problems loading blockchain from existing folder

Tags: blockchain

I once saved the "blocks" folder + the "index" folder of the Bitcoin wallet.

Now on another PC I thought I could load the chain that way by copy pasting these folders in Appdata. Wasn't very smart not to copy directly the whole file folder.

So in my situation what else do I need exactly to properly launch the wallet with a full blockchain ? Please help I don't want to download the chain again...

I get this error:

```
2017-02-01 02:56:15 ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk(CBlock&, CBlockIndex*): GetHash() doesn't match index for CBlockIndex(pprev=0xd4ba3c0, nHeight=299478, merkle=4f27a1a8c5f19894e7012ce4ea4f83eba0ea846af888749980d85‌​5e5d7179e46, hashBlock=00000000000000001e66b8d27a6bcff234f06d502a01aa23fd‌​4be311d8b2dbf2) at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=138, nPos=8)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If blocks/ and blocks/index/ are present, recent versions of Bitcoin Core will process the blocks in it, and rebuild chainstate/ at startup.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error doing this?

Comment: Sorry haven't checked the error log. It says :

2017-02-01 02:56:15 ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk(CBlock&, CBlockIndex*): GetHash() doesn't match index for CBlockIndex(pprev=0xd4ba3c0, nHeight=299478, merkle=4f27a1a8c5f19894e7012ce4ea4f83eba0ea846af888749980d855e5d7179e46, hashBlock=00000000000000001e66b8d27a6bcff234f06d502a01aa23fd4be311d8b2dbf2) at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=138, nPos=8)
2017-02-01 02:56:15 *** Failed to read block

Which block file is in cause ? I don't know what to do.

Comment: This means your blocks/ and blocks/index do not correspond. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you will also need the `chainstate` folder in order to properly run from a backup. Other files/folders are not strictly needed to restart your daemon. More information concerning specific folders can be found here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory

If all else fails start the process with `-reindex` and let it run - it "only" takes 24-48 hours depending on your bandwidth. Even though I know you don't want that!

Comment: His problem is that the blocks/ and blocks/index are out of sync, but this answer (using -reindex) will fix that too. It's also inevitable, as he needs to build the chainstate anyway.

Comment: Okay. How much space is the full chainstate folder ? If not too heavy could someone please upload it via wetransfer ? My mail lau.w@live.fr